# Having difficulties to connect my static site and postgreSQL server on render.com (NestJS, TypeORM)

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, render.com

Static and SQL Server are hosted. I can connect to Render's SQL Server from my local machine using external URL for the connection.

https://i.imgur.com/Rx1jOtK.jpg

This is my code that I don't change for production mode.

```
export const dataSourceConfig: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: "postgres",
  entities: ["dist/**/*.entity.js"],
  migrations: ["dist/db/migrations/*.js"],
  subscribers: ["dist/subscribers/**/*{.js,.ts}"],
  url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
};
```

After deployment, I set up the .env variables. I've tried all three suggested methods

https://i.imgur.com/YpImKjm.jpg

I change the DATABASE_URL to the internal URL. However, I'm unable to connect to the SQL server. Also, I don't see any connections in my log between the server while the site deploys my static site after a new commit.

I appreciate every suggestion on where to look for help, whether I've made a mistake in connecting on the website itself or if the issue is in the code. I've hit a wall and have no idea what to do, partly because the logs are not of much help. (which can, I have no doubt, be utilized in a more advanced way; I use them as presented to free users on the website)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used a 'static site' instead of a 'web service' to host my site.

The static site option uses Next.js' export feature to generate static assets (e.g. html/css, frontend JS files), which means that Next is not handling incoming requests. When run using the web service option, Next.js is run as a Node server, and features like API routes & SSR behave as expected.